# JS confirm method to toggle vuetify checkbox in vue 2

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

things are getting super hectic with this attempt. I just have a v-dialog, inside of it is a checkbox. When you click the checkbox, we runs a confirm() method to open browser focused dialog to confirm you want to click that checkbox.

When I hit okay, confirm it. the checkbox does not change, but the value of override does. When I hit it again, it then of course flips override over again and now its backwards.

When I hit cancel, the cancel does prevent any changes from happening.

im super lost here and have been digging through some similar examples on here, which is where i came up with the click.native concept.

Before I had the click.native.capture it wouldnt even try to stop it. I think the answer is somewhere in that stop request.

```
<v-checkbox
  ref="checkbox"
  dense
  :value="override"
  @click.native.capture="showConfirmationDialog($event)"
  class="pa-0 pl-5 ma-0 mt-3"
  label="Manually apply sale Price. WARNING: Will turn off auto updates."
></v-checkbox>
```

and the method:

```
showConfirmationDialog(event) {
  if (!this.override) {
    const result = confirm(
      'The action you are requesting will remove this product from automatic payment adjustments and information. You will need to re-apply the item in order to turn this back on. Are you sure you wish to continue?'
    );

    if (result) {
      this.override = true;
    } else {
      event.preventDefault();
      event.stopPropagation();
    }
  } else {
    this.override = false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `v-model` and then immediately set the value back to false on the next UI update tick using [nextTick](https://vuejs.org/api/general.html#nexttick) if the result is false. This way you're not fighting Vuetify, you just wait for v-checkbox to finish it's thing then flip the value to be correct. It should appear seamless. It's also ok with this to just use standard `@click`

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <v-checkbox
      ref="checkbox"
      dense
      v-model="override"
      @click="showConfirmationDialog"
      class="pa-0 pl-5 ma-0 mt-3"
      label="Manually apply sale Price. WARNING: Will turn off auto updates."
    ></v-checkbox>
  </div>
</template>
```

```js
showConfirmationDialog() {
  if (this.override) {
    const result = confirm(
      'The action you are requesting will remove this product from automatic payment adjustments and information. You will need to re-apply the item in order to turn this back on. Are you sure you wish to continue?'
    );

    if (result) {
      this.override = true;
    } else {
      this.$nextTick(() => {
        this.override = false;
      });
    }
  } else {
    this.override = false;
  }
}
```

Comment: this worked. Thank you. good lord i tried so many different combinations lol. Ty very much.